# Translate shell script not working within Automator

Tags: terminal, bash, automator, script

I have this code to translate a word from/to English/Spanish:

```
S=`/usr/local/bin/trans -b -id -no-ansi "$a" | grep Code | awk '{print $2}'`
if [ "$S" = "en" ]; then T=es; else T=en; fi
/usr/local/bin/trans -b :"$T" "$a"
```

(`trans` is from https://github.com/soimort/translate-shell/)

Running the script straight in Terminal (bash) works great.

But when I try to use it in Automator, I get this error:

`/usr/local/bin/trans: line 5073: gawk: command not found`

Running `gawk` in Terminal also works fine.

---

**UPDATE**: Thanks to solver below, final working script for automator is:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
S=`/usr/local/bin/trans -b -id -no-ansi "$@" | grep Code | awk '{print $2}'`
if [ "$S" = "en" ]; then T=es; else T=en; fi
/usr/local/bin/trans -b :"$T" "$@"
```

Comment: The [useless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html) is easy to fix; replace `grep x | awk '{y}'` with `awk '/x/ {y}'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default `PATH` passed to the Run Shell Script *action* in Automator is:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

I always add a `PATH=...`, where `...` is the actual `PATH` used in Terminal, to the top of the Run Shell Script *action* in Automator.

Or you have to add the fully qualified pathname of any executable to the command line that is not in the default `PATH` passed to the Run Shell Script *action* in Automator.

---

The last line in the `trans` *script* is `gawk -f <(echo -E "$TRANS_PROGRAM") - "$@"` and unless `gawk` is in the default `PATH` passed you'll need to add the location of `gawk` to the `PATH` you pass to the Run Shell Script *action* in Automator, or add the fully qualified pathname to the `gawk` command at the end of the `trans` *script*.

In Terminal use `which gawk` to get its path, e.g.:

```
which gawk
/usr/local/bin/gawk
```

In `trans`, change:

```
gawk -f <(echo -E "$TRANS_PROGRAM") - "$@"
```

To:

```
/usr/local/bin/gawk -f <(echo -E "$TRANS_PROGRAM") - "$@"
```

Or in the Run Shell Script *action* in Automator, e.g.:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

Or use the `PATH` from the output of `echo $PATH` in Terminal.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks! Tried to fix your typo `which gwak` but site won't let me change less than 6 characters.

Comment: @Ze'ev Haven't had coffee yet this morning, I fixed it, thanks.