# Why would a python3 script not find a module when run in Automator?

Tags: macos, automator, script, python

I am trying to automatically run a python script using automator. This script 
`python3 ~/Desktop/python/gmaps.py`
works fine in terminal but not when I try to run it through Automator , I get a "module pyperclip cannot be found", even though it is found fine when running from terminal.

I can not figure out what would cause the path to be different. Is there a guide to command line plus Automator ?

Comment: Assuming Catalina as OS and anaconda and brew (+python3) installed you might have three different python3 execs.

Comment: It’s probably not as simple as a [path error](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/270540/). Are you running bash python in the script? Seeing a bit more of how exactly you’re calling things with an edit to the post would be ideal.

Comment: The `PATH` passed to a **Run Shell Script** _action_ in **Automator** is: `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` So you need to add the appropriate _environment variables_. Using _fully qualified pathnames_ of the _executable_ is also an _option_, however you may need to add `python` specific _environment variables_ as well as a `PATH` _statement_.

Answer (score 3):

Another option for running in automator without having to reinstall the module is to provide the path to the instance of python that you want used.

e.g. I used Homebrew to install python3
so I use the following in Automator to run that instance of python

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/bin/python3
```

Source: [VikingOSX reply here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8392208)

Answer (score 1):

Solved:
I'm not sure why it worked, but running `pip3 install pyperclip` in the automator window installed it in the correct location for it to be used.